# ActiveX / XPCOM equivalent for Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, activex, clipboard, xpcom

Is there any way in Google Chrome to access the clipboard (i.e. get and set content of clipboard)? Internet Explorer allows for this by using ActiveX and I got it working in Firefox via XPCOM, I am wondering if there is any way to do this in Chrome?

What I want is to be able to intercept the "paste" events in JavaScript and pre-process the content of the clipboard before it's being pasted into the website's textarea (or RTE in my case).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [NPAPI](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org); you can use it to create a plugin that will work in all browsers (works both as a NPAPI plugin and an ActiveX control)

Answer (score 0):

NPAPI has been deprecated. Use [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/).